# Getting CreationTime from PNG

Tags: c#, datetime, png, exif, exiftool

I'm coding a winForm application that renames images with the datetime taken.
e.g. Original image name => Image_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS

I was using GetPropertyItem(36867) which is the Exif Date/Time Origin.
But this only works on JPG, not PNG.
As far as I know PNG does not have exif until recent versions and the closest thing in PNG is CreationTime. Also, I've come across a discussion thread about calling exiftool in console.

Is it possible to get the date/time without exiftool?
Or how can I implement exiftool into my c# GUI program without adding too much complexity?

Comment: You should take note that PNG files rarely have embedded metadata in the first place.  The file system create (and modify date) as mentioned by @Ethan are likely the best you can do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`File.GetCreationTime(file path)` from the `System.IO` namespace is the best you can (reliably) do. Unfortunately PNG metadata doesn't usually contian a creation date so getting the write date is the best you can do. For more information on how to use this, read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=net-6.0